# Trying to get an anagram program to work

Tags: java, anagram

I'm doing a project for school that requires me to program an anagram finder through the following steps:

1. Write a method that reads the words from an dictionary file (just a regular text file) into an array of strings
2. Write a method that creates an array of letter counts for a word (each array should have 26 elements; the k-th element represents the number of times the k-th letter of the alphabet occurs in a word)
3. Write a method that compares two letter count arrays for an exact match
4. For each word in the dictionary, generate a letter count array, compare it with the letter count array for the target word, and print out the word if they match.

My code compiles but doesn't print anything out, what am I doing wrong?

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Anagram 
{

static String[] words; 

public static String[] readFile(String pathName){          
    List <String> dictionary = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(pathName));            
        while (sc.hasNextLine()){
            dictionary.add(sc.nextLine());
        }                      

    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex){
        System.out.println("*** Cannot open " + pathName + " ***");
        System.exit(1);        
    }

    words = new String[dictionary.size()];
    dictionary.toArray(words);

    return words;

}

public static int[] letterCount(String str){

    int[] count = new int[26];

    for(int i = 0; i< str.length(); i++){
        char ch = str.charAt(i);
        int value = (int) ch;
        if (value >= 97 && value <= 122){
            count[ch - 'a']++;
        }       
    }

    return count;
}

public static boolean sameChar (String firstStr, String secondStr){

    if(firstStr.length() != secondStr.length())
        return false;

    int[] a = letterCount(firstStr);
    int[] b = letterCount(secondStr);              
    return (a == b);       

}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here

    System.out.println("Enter target word: ");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String targetWord = scanner.nextLine();

    readFile("words.txt");
    for(String word: words) {
        if(sameChar(word, targetWord) == true){
            System.out.println(word + " ");
        }

    }   
}
 }
```

Comment: For a start `String [] words = readFile("words.txt");` and get rid of the  static declaration of `words` - declare variables where you are going to use them, reduce scope

Comment: You can't compare the contents of int-array with `a == b`. Look up `Arrays.equals`

Comment: If you call `words` in the `main()` scope, declare it there as well

Comment: you are comparing words with whole sentences. user inputs a word and you compare with each line of text in the file. you need to split the sentences from the file into words

Comment: @JackFlamp all of the words are on individual lines, they don't need to be split up :)

Comment: Minor note: `System.out.println(word + " ");` prints a new line, so the space at the end is unnecessary, unless you change it to `System.out.print(word + " ");`

Comment: @LanceToth noted! thanks :)